# Rockrider 8.1 rack and bags

Tags: touring, rack, panniers

I'll do a bike trip that will last a week and I need to mount a rear rack.

My bike is a Rockrider 8.1 with disc brakes without threaded seat-stay bosses to attach the mounting bracket arms.

A friend lent me these bags http://www.decathlon.it/borse-bici-2x20-litri-classic-id_8248119.html

How can I attach a rack to my bike to use these bags?

Comment: Rockrider is a brand sold by a single chain store (Decathlon). Would it not be a good idea to ask them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reasonably study aluminum tube rack should be okay. Panniers and racks use a standard for mounting, so any rack that looks like this should be okay.

http://www.nashbar.com/bikes/Product_10053_10052_519792_-1___202601

[image: Nashbar Mtn Rack]

An mtn bike specific rack like that one is probably a good choice since it 
will be wider to have more clearance, but most bike racks should work if you
use skinnier MTB tires. The important part is something to hook the lower pannier connection on just above the lower mounts. Avoid older racks with hinged parts, these simply won't stand up to the load.

The tricky part is mounting the rack to the seat stays. You can do this using P-clamps from the hardware store.

[image: P-clamp]

Here's an example:

http://www.homedepot.com/p/t/100130546?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053&N=5yc1v&R=100130546

If you are using P-clamps for both upper and lower attachements, it would be a good idea to keep the weight as low as possible. You can also get brackets that work with a long skewer on the rear axle, but I'm not sure that's worth it for a single week long trip.

And if you've got money burning a hole in your pocket and want a solid long term solution.

http://www.oldmanmountain.com/

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same bike and problem, I went into decathlon to ask if they could fit a rack but they told me it was not possible. Talk about a can-do attitude!

I got a decathlon pannier rack anyway (making sure it was marked as disk compatible). I was able to fit it using "tubus clamps", which are basically a beefed up p clip. I needed two sets, for the top and bottoms of the seat stays.

With these in place the pannier rack fits OK and is very sturdy, it can quite comfortable carry 20kg.